# JQuery - Change the ajax data source of my datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I currently have the following script on my page:

HTML+JS Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<select>
  <option value="data_20160712">data_20160712</option>
  <option value="data_20160711">data_20160711</option>
</select>     
</br></br></br></br>  
    <table id="data0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>F1</th>
                <th>F2</th>
                <th>F3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>F1</th>
                <th>F2</th>
                <th>F3</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/dataRender/datetime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#data0 tfoot th').each(function(i) {
            var title0 = $('#data0 thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
            $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title0 + '" data-index="' + i + '" />');
        });

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#data0').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 10,
            "lengthChange": true,
            responsive: true,
            //fixedHeader: false,
            "scrollX": true,
            "ajax": "data_20160712.json",
            deferRender: true,
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            buttons: [{
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    title: "data_20160712"
                }, {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    title: "data_20160712"
                }, {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    title: "data_20160712"
                }, ]
                //FIX HEADER SIZE
        });
        // Apply the search
        table.columns().every(function() {
            var that = this;

            $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
                if (that.search() !== this.value) {
                    that
                        .search(this.value)
                        .draw();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</html>
```

**data_20160712.json:**

```
{"data": [
    ["20160712","20160712","20160712"],
    ["20160712","20160712","20160712"],
    ["20160712","20160712","20160712"]
]
}
```

**data_20160711.json:**

```
{"data": [
    ["20160711","20160711","20160711"],
    ["20160711","20160711","20160711"],
    ["20160711","20160711","20160711"]
]
}
```

[image: Example]

How can I control the **YYYYMMDD** value dynamically with another function and a select box on the page so that the data in the datable updates dynamically when the data source changes?

Thanks for your help.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/airgonomike/bga5bt9g/3/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain what your question is, but I suspect it involves the [.ajax.reload()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) method of datatables.

You can then do whatever you wish to the data and call the above function to refresh the data.

Comment: ajax.reload() would be good if I was always pointing to the same json file.

What I want it to basically use the select element to update the "ajax": "data_20160712.json" and get the table to reload dynamically this way.

Comment: I think it's explained here: https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.url().load()

I just don't quite get how I can do it in practice with a select box...

Comment: @Rgonomike OK, glad to see you found a solution, but its very oddly structured with a mix of jQuery and plain javascript. This should set you straight:
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/
Essentially use

    $( "#myselect" ).val();
or 
    $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();

Depending on whether you want the value or the text of the selection. 

If you have any control at all over your data source I'd suggest you look at refactoring it so you can do something like get /api/data?date=

Comment: Thanks. I changed the function to:
function getSelValue() {
    console.log($( "#sel option:selected" ).text());
    $('#data0').DataTable().ajax.url('json/'+$( "#sel option:selected" ).text()+'.json').load();
}

Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed!

```
<select id='sel' onchange="getSelValue()">
  <option value="data_20160712">data_20160712</option>
  <option value="data_20160711">data_20160711</option>
</select>
```

And I added a script the replaces the data source the way I need when the selected value changes:

```
<script>
function getSelValue() {
    //console.log($( "#sel option:selected" ).text());
    $('#data0').DataTable().ajax.url('json/'+$( "#sel option:selected" ).text()+'.json').load();
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<select id='sel' onchange="getSelValue()">
  <option value="data_20160712">data_20160712</option>
  <option value="data_20160711">data_20160711</option>
</select>     
<p id="inhtml"></p>
</br></br></br></br>  
<table id="data0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"> 
    <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Field1</th>
   <th>Field2</th>
   <th>Field3</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tfoot>
  <tr>
   <th>SP Code</th>
   <th>SP Name</th>
   <th>Contract number</th>
  </tr>
 </tfoot>
</table>
</body>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.2/js/dataTables.scroller.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/dataRender/datetime.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
        $('#data0 tfoot th').each( function (i) {
            var title0 = $('#data0 thead th').eq( $(this).index() ).text();
            $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title0+'" data-index="'+i+'" />' );
        } );

        // DataTable
        var table = $('#data0').DataTable( {
            "pageLength": 10,
            "lengthChange": true,
            responsive: true,
            //fixedHeader: false,
            "scrollX": true,
            "ajax": "json/data_20160712.json", 
            deferRender:    true,
            dom: 'Blfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    title: "data_20160712"
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csvHtml5',
                    title: "data_20160712"
                },
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    title: "data_20160712"
                },
            ]
        //FIX HEADER SIZE
        } );
        // Apply the search
            table.columns().every( function () {
                var that= this;

                $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                    if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                        that
                            .search( this.value )
                            .draw();
                    }
                } );
            } );
    } );
</script>
<script>
function getSelValue() {
    //console.log($( "#sel option:selected" ).text());
    $('#data0').DataTable().ajax.url('json/'+$( "#sel option:selected" ).text()+'.json').load();
}
</script>
</html>
```